# Recursive function won't call another function n number of times

Tags: python

I am working on an exercise in Think Python 2nd edition. The directions are as follows:

> Write a function called do_n that takes a function object and a number, n, as arguments, and that calls the given function n times.

Here is my code:

```
def print_once(s):
    print(s)
    
def do_n(func, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        print_once(s)
        do_n(func, n - 1)

do_n(print_once('Bob'), 3)
```

My function do_n was correct according to what I found online, but I cannot understand why it does not call print_once 3 times.

Comment: Unless they are specifically telling you to define a recursive function, don't use recursion to implement a simple loop.

Comment: You never use `func`, and you never specify a value of `s` for use inside `do_n`.

Comment: You are calling `do_n(None, 3)`, since None is the return value of `print_once('Bob')`.  You have to pass an actual function to `do_n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the previous solution would not work, since it is not passing the callable to `do_n`, but instead calling the function `print_once` before moving to `do_n`. Here is a fully functional version with a slight change to the original code:

```
def print_once(s):
    print(s)

def do_n(func, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        func('Bob')
        do_n(func, n - 1)

do_n(print_once, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't pass a function object to the recursive function. You only call the `print_once()` which returns `None`.

```
def print_once(s):
    print(s)

def do_n(func, func_arg, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        func(func_arg)   
        do_n(func, func_arg, n - 1)

# this is a function call it returns
# nothing according to the definition
# of the print_once function

# do_n(print_once('Bob'), 3)


# this is a function object passed
# to the do_n function. The argument to
# the function is also passed to do_n
do_n(print_once, "Bob", 3)
```

If you want to call a function bound to its argument, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.partial)

```
print_once_bob = functools.partial(print_once, "Bob")
do_n(print_once_bob, 3)
```

Comment: This throws an error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: The reason being `print_once` returns `None`; `do_n`'s body would try to use it as a callable, yielding the `TypeError`.

Comment: There's no point passing `print_once` as an argument if you don't actually call `func` inside the function, though.

Comment: But you still have to provide an argument for `func`, since `print_once` expects one.